# Как записать аудио с микрофона в файл?

Tags: python, python-2.x, аудио

Как записать аудио с микрофона в файл в windows?

Comment: Какое аудио? Как и откуда оно получено?

Comment: Записать надо с микрофона аудио и вывести его в файл

Comment: Я что-то такое делал, но в рамке совершенно другой задачи: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e3f1a1a6fd23fef9cabe2d36557d8c9e8e9635f4/speech_recognition/write_audio___from_microphone.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать с при помощи pyaudio. 
Пример с официального [сайта](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)

```
python -m pip install pyaudio

"""PyAudio example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```